# Trouble scraping with scrapy

Tags: python, web, scrapy

Here is my code guys, to explain first of all I scraped listing links, then I yielded response to go through every link of a listing and then parse some info e.g name,address,price,number. While running it in terminal I get some errors such as     (price = response.css('div.article_right_price::text').get().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'), but I still can export it into csv without problem, but one thing this particular language is Georgian and when I export it to CSV i only see symbols which are not georgian :)) i would be grateful if someone could help me.

```
import scrapy


class SsHomesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ss_home'
    start_urls = ['https://ss.ge/ka/udzravi-qoneba/l/bina/qiravdeba?CurrentUserId=&Query=&MunicipalityId=95&CityIdList=95&subdistr=&stId=&PrcSource=2&StatusField.FieldId=34&StatusField.Type=SingleSelect&StatusField.StandardField=Status&StatusField.SelectedValues=2&QuantityFrom=&QuantityTo=&PriceType=false&CurrencyId=2&PriceFrom=300&PriceTo=500&Context.Request.Query%5BQuery%5D=&IndividualEntityOnly=true&Fields%5B3%5D.FieldId=151&Fields%5B3%5D.Type=SingleSelect&Fields%5B3%5D.StandardField=None&Fields%5B4%5D.FieldId=150&Fields%5B4%5D.Type=SingleSelect&Fields%5B4%5D.StandardField=None&Fields%5B5%5D.FieldId=152&Fields%5B5%5D.Type=SingleSelect&Fields%5B5%5D.StandardField=None&Fields%5B6%5D.FieldId=29&Fields%5B6%5D.Type=SingleSelect&Fields%5B6%5D.StandardField=None&Fields%5B7%5D.FieldId=153&Fields%5B7%5D.Type=MultiSelect&Fields%5B7%5D.StandardField=None&Fields%5B8%5D.FieldId=30&Fields%5B8%5D.Type=SingleSelect&Fields%5B8%5D.StandardField=None&Fields%5B0%5D.FieldId=48&Fields%5B0%5D.Type=Number&Fields%5B0%5D.StandardField=None&Fields%5B0%5D.ValueFrom=&Fields%5B0%5D.ValueTo=&Fields%5B1%5D.FieldId=146&Fields%5B1%5D.Type=Number&Fields%5B1%5D.StandardField=None&Fields%5B1%5D.ValueFrom=&Fields%5B1%5D.ValueTo=&Fields%5B2%5D.FieldId=28&Fields%5B2%5D.Type=Number&Fields%5B2%5D.StandardField=Floor&Fields%5B2%5D.ValueFrom=&Fields%5B2%5D.ValueTo=&Fields%5B9%5D.FieldId=15&Fields%5B9%5D.Type=Group&Fields%5B9%5D.StandardField=None&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B0%5D.Value=35&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B1%5D.Value=36&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B2%5D.Value=37&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B3%5D.Value=38&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B4%5D.Value=39&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B5%5D.Value=40&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B6%5D.Value=41&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B7%5D.Value=42&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B8%5D.Value=24&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B9%5D.Value=27&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B10%5D.Value=22&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B11%5D.Value=20&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B12%5D.Value=8&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B13%5D.Value=6&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B14%5D.Value=4&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B15%5D.Value=5&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B16%5D.Value=9&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B17%5D.Value=3&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B18%5D.Value=120&AgencyId=&VipStatus=&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B0%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B1%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B2%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B3%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B4%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B5%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B6%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B7%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B8%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B9%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B10%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B11%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B12%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B13%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B14%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B15%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B16%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B17%5D.Selected=false&Fields%5B9%5D.Values%5B18%5D.Selected=false']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_listing = response.css('div.latest_desc a::attr(href)')
        for list in all_listing:
            yield response.follow(list.get(), callback=self.parse_listings)


    def parse_listings(self, response):
        name = response.css('div.article_in_title h1::text').get()
        price = response.css('div.article_right_price::text').get().strip()
        square_m = response.css('div.WholeFartBlock text::text').get().strip()
        street = response.css('div.StreeTaddressList a::text').get().strip()
        number = response.css('div.UserMObileNumbersBlock a::attr(href)').get().strip("tel':")

        yield {
            'name': name,
             'price': price,
             'square_m': square_m,
             'street': street,
            'number': number
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is not `scrapy` related. You are calling method `strip()` on a `None` object. Your selectors are returning `None` instead of the string value you are expecting. Check your selectors again and also consider using [`scrapy itemloaders`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) to clean your items.